# How to include llvm/IR/Module.h in c++ on Mac / OS X?

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, compiler-errors, llvm

I'm trying to compile a simple file which requires llvm headers.

```
#include <llvm/IR/Module.h>
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

I am on mac os. I use following command to compile the code.

```
g++ s.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --system-libs --ldflags --libs core`
```

Do I need to build llvm from source code ?
Is there anything missing ?

Comment: What errors do you see? You may need to install LLVM. e.g. `brew install llvm`

Comment: I ended up using ubuntu 14.04 in docker and installed llvm in it.

Comment: Wouldn't brew install llvm built-in llvm which comes with os x.

Comment: I tried this. llvm got installed but I get the same error.

Comment: Can you post the output of `llvm-config --cxxflags --system-libs --ldflags --libs core`

Comment: Also post the error that you get

Comment: Output of llvm-config --cxxflags --system-libs --ldflags --libs core
-bash: llvm-config: command not found
and error message is 
`
In file included from main.cpp:5:
./CodeGenVisitor.cpp:5:10: fatal error: 'llvm/IR/Module.h' file not found
#include <llvm/IR/Module.h>
         ^
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install LLVM, it is not provided by the system, and Xcode does not ship one that you can actually use (other than clang for compiling C/C++/ObjC, and swift-c for Swift).
You can either grab a binary release from llvm.org, or use brew, or build it from source!